# ASP.NET Mobile Friendly URL's

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to set ASP.Net URL friendly URL's.
For some reason its working fine for Desktop but not for Mobile Pages.

For Ex:

Desktop
a) Type URL : www.foo.com/login
  -> Working fine

Mobile
a) Type URL : www.foo.com/login
  -> Error

The reason for error is,login page is not taking the controls for Master page on mobile phone and throwing exception for same.It might be taking the master page of Site.Mobile.Master on mobile devices.

Thanks

Comment: What we can do to avoid site.master.mobile page.

Comment: Would it solve the problem to add the login control to the site.master.mobile page? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1885742/3585500

Comment: Already tried but still the same problem

Comment: Ah, sorry! To avoid the site.master.mobile page [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20678189/3585500) says to just delete it. But read the other answers below it because there's a lot newer that might fix later issues.

Comment: Well i tried all combinations,nothing worked and the issue is resolved finally by getting rid of friendly URL's Thanks Kapil Suri